# How to insert date and time in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g, syntax-error

I'm doing a java project in Netbeans IDE with JDBC oracle database.And,I need to insert date and time in to the database, which is in format **11/16/2013 10:30**.
I have attached my codes below.

Insert code in **DBConnector**

```
public void insert(String id, String uid, String vmid, String ttid, String faid, String taid, String fdate, String tdate, String onbooking, String msbooking, String bcreated)
            throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query = "Insert into DMUSER.CAB2("
                + "ID,"
                + "USER_ID,"
                + "VEHICLE_MODEL_ID,"
                + "TRAVEL_TYPE_ID,"
                + "FROM_AREA_ID,"
                + "TO_AREA_ID,"
                + "FROM_DATE,"
                + "TO_DATE,"
                + "ONLINE_BOOKING,"
                + "MOBILE_SITE_BOOKING,"
                + "BOOKING_CREATED"
                + ") values ("
                + id + ","
                + uid + ","
                + vmid + ","
                + ttid + ","
                + faid + ","
                + taid + ","
                + fdate + ","
                + tdate + ","
                + onbooking + ","
                + msbooking + ","
                + bcreated + ""
                + ")";
```

Button Click events

```
private void btn_insertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    txt_id.setText("132536");
    txt_user_id.setText("16");
    txt_vechile_mdl_id.setText("28");
    txt_from_area_id.setText("58");
    txt_to_area_id.setText("1063");
    txt_frm_date.setText("11/16/2013 9:30");
    txt_to_date.setText("NULL");
    txt_booking_created.setText("11/16/2013 9:30");
    txt_travel_type_id.setText("2");
    txt_mobile_site_booking.setText("0");
    txt_online_booking.setText("1");
} 

private void btn_predictionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        try {

            String id = txt_id.getText();
            String uid = txt_user_id.getText();
            String vmid = txt_vechile_mdl_id.getText();
            String ttid = txt_travel_type_id.getText();
            String faid = txt_from_area_id.getText();
            String fdate = txt_frm_date.getText();
            String tdate = txt_to_date.getText();
            String onbooking = txt_online_booking.getText();
            String msbooking = txt_mobile_site_booking.getText();
            String bcreated = txt_booking_created.getText();
            String taid = txt_to_area_id.getText();

            DB_Connector con = new DB_Connector();

            try {
                con.insert(id, uid, vmid, ttid, faid, taid, fdate, tdate, onbooking, msbooking, bcreated);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
```

Logger.getLogger(CabCancellationUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

The problem here is, in database the date column is in `VARCHAR` datatype,so how can I insert this **11/16/2013 10:30** into database.Please help me to sort this out.

Edited: exception occurred

> QUERY::  Insert into
>   DMUSER.CAB2(ID,USER_ID,VEHICLE_MODEL_ID,TRAVEL_TYPE_ID,FROM_AREA_ID,TO_AREA_ID,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,ONLINE_BOOKING,MOBILE_SITE_BOOKING,BOOKING_CREATED)
>   values (132536,16,28,2,58,1063,11/16/2013 10:30,NULL,1,0,01)
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma
>
> at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1706)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1674)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:275)
>     at Database.DB_Connector.insert(DB_Connector.java:78)   at
>   UI.CabCancellationUI.btn_predictionActionPerformed(CabCancellationUI.java:365)
>     at UI.CabCancellationUI.access$500(CabCancellationUI.java:28)   at
>   UI.CabCancellationUI$6.actionPerformed(CabCancellationUI.java:151)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java

Comment: what problem/exception did you encountered when running your code

Comment: I have updated the question with Exception,please check

Comment: Problem #1 - parameterize all your inputs to the INSERT statement.  If yo don't want to do that (and you should), date/time literals need to be enclosed in quotes, i.e. '11/16/2013 10:30' , and If you still want to use literals, you should not depend in the default oracle date format, which can vary between systems, so should call to_date() to convert. but REALLY use parameters instead so you don't have to worry about atll that crap.

Comment: you should use PreparedStatement or properly locate ' characters in your sql like `"'" + id + "','" + uid + "',"`

Comment: @ OldProgrammer how can I use parameter,can you please give me an example

Comment: @guleryuz But I got this exception,only when I insert the date in the above format,otherwise my code is working fine.

Comment: you should do them for all varchar fields as other commentors and answerers suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not what you thought. The exception is complaining about wrong sql-syntax for inserting data.

You need to correct your query-string in the insert method. Also, each of the table-columns you've accepted as string, which seems incorrect. Think about the proper datatype for each column of the table, like ID should be number, not a varchar,etc.

If every parameter is of type string, then the correct code wold have to add `'` everywhere before and after the parameters in the query string as shown below :

```
String query = "Insert into DMUSER.CAB2("
            + "ID,"
            + "USER_ID,"
            + "VEHICLE_MODEL_ID,"
            + "TRAVEL_TYPE_ID,"
            + "FROM_AREA_ID,"
            + "TO_AREA_ID,"
            + "FROM_DATE,"
            + "TO_DATE,"
            + "ONLINE_BOOKING,"
            + "MOBILE_SITE_BOOKING,"
            + "BOOKING_CREATED"
            + ") values ("
            + "'"+ id + "',"
            + "'" + uid + "',"
            + "'" + vmid + "',"
            + "'" + ttid + "',"
            + "'" + faid + "',"
            + "'" + taid + "',"
            + "'" + fdate + "',"
            + "'" + tdate + "',"
            + "'" + onbooking + "',"
            + "'"+ msbooking + "',"
            + "'"+bcreated + "'"
            + ")";
```

Lastly, this is a terrible code. You should think of using PreparedStatement.

Comment: Yes,I misunderstood the exception.working fine now.Thank you

Comment: @temp - But, look at the suggestions I have given. Try PreparedStatements, use Integer datatypes for ID's, date for date-types,etc. Also, keep on exploring more about the same. Good Luck, :)

Comment: yea,Okey.Thank you again :)